# R Amending FF Factors

Tags: r, ff

I am using **Factors** to handle character strings in FF.

> tt <- ff(factor(c("a","b","c")),names=c("c1","c2","c3"))
>   tt
>   ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: a b c
>   c1 c2 c3 
>    a  b  c

When I try to change one of the data items I get the following:

> tt["c2"] <- "d"
>   Warning message:
>   In ram2ffcode(value, fflev, vmode) : unknown factor values mapped to NA

Any ideas how to change the data to get:

> ff (open) integer length=3 (3) levels: a c d
>   c1 c2 c3 
>    a  d  c